# How to realize curvate bracket after which two formulas follow in vertical order

Tags: equations, brackets

I would like to write a equation which defines quantity `f(X)` to be `a` if `X>0` and `b` else. I would like to do so writing `f(X)=` followed by a curvate bracket and then `a if x>0` and `b else` aligned vertically.

By curvate bracket I mean a `\bigg` version of `{`.

Comment: see the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
a\qquad\text{if } x>0\\b\qquad\text{if } x\le0
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}`.  Additional options are possible if `a` and `b` are different widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package provides the simplest way to break out a function into different cases.  But one can see in the first example that the alignment of the right portion will be affected by the width of what is on the left.  Thus, `cases` supports the use of the alignment tab `&` to separate and align columns of the case, as shown in the 2nd case.

With the `*` version of the environment (example 3), which is provided by the `mathtools` package, the right-hand portion of the case is set as text automatically.

With `dcases` family of environments, also from the `mathtools` package, the math is set in `\displaystyle` automatically (example 4).

As you can see from the comments, there are many environments in the `cases` family, and one should (myself included) study the documentation to get them all straight.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  a \quad\text{if } x>0\\
  b \quad\text{if } x\le0
\end{cases}
\]
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  a & \text{if } x>0\\
  b & \text{if } x\le0
\end{cases}
\]
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{cases*}
 \frac{a}{b}    &  if  $x>0$\\
 b_3  &  for all other situations
\end{cases*}
\]
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{dcases*}
 \frac{a}{b}    &  if  $x>0$\\
 b_3  &  for all other situations
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, `amsmath`’s `cases` environment supports the use of `&` as well.  On the other hand, if you load `mathtools`, you could directly use `dcases*` and spare the `\text{...}`.

Comment: The main difference between `cases` and `dcases` is that former sets its material in text-style math mode and the latter typesets its material is **d**isplay-style math mode. As Gustavo has already pointed out, both environments use `&` to separate the assertion and conditioning information parts.

Comment: @Mico: You’re right, `dcases` (with the `d`) serves no purpose in this case.  I’d simply go for `cases*`.

Comment: @Mico So many environments, so little time.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: That’s the joy of `mathtools`! (;-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Note that `cases*` *does* require `mathtools` too.